# transpose for 8 registers of 16-bit elements on SSE2/SSSE3

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86, sse, simd

(I'm a newbie to SSE/asm, apologies if this is obvious or redundant)

Is there a better way to transpose 8 SSE registers containing 16-bit values than performing 24 unpck[lh]ps and 8/16+ shuffles and using 8 extra registers? (Note using up to SSSE 3 instructions, Intel Merom, aka lacking BLEND* from SSE4.)

Say you have registers v[0-7] and use t0-t7 as aux registers. In pseudo intrinsics code:

```
/* Phase 1: process lower parts of the registers */
/* Level 1: work first part of the vectors */
/*   v[0]  A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
**   v[1]  B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
**   v[2]  C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
**   v[3]  D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7
**   v[4]  E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7
**   v[5]  F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7
**   v[6]  G0 G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7
**   v[7]  H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 */
t0 = unpcklps (v[0], v[1]); /* Extract first half interleaving */
t1 = unpcklps (v[2], v[3]); /* Extract first half interleaving */
t2 = unpcklps (v[4], v[5]); /* Extract first half interleaving */
t3 = unpcklps (v[6], v[7]); /* Extract first half interleaving */
t0 = pshufhw (t0, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t0 = pshuflw (t0, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t1 = pshufhw (t1, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t1 = pshuflw (t1, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t2 = pshufhw (t2, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t2 = pshuflw (t2, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t3 = pshufhw (t3, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t3 = pshuflw (t3, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
/*   t0   A0 B0 A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3  (A B - 0 1 2 3)
**   t1   C0 D0 C1 D1 C2 D2 C3 D3  (C D - 0 1 2 3)
**   t2   E0 F0 E1 F1 E2 F2 E3 F3  (E F - 0 1 2 3)
**   t3   G0 H0 G1 H1 G2 H2 G3 H3  (G H - 0 1 2 3) */
/* L2 */
t4 = unpcklps (t0, t1);
t5 = unpcklps (t2, t3);
t6 = unpckhps (t0, t1);
t7 = unpckhps (t2, t3);
/*   t4   A0 B0 C0 D0 A1 B1 C1 D1 (A B C D - 0 1)
**   t5   E0 F0 G0 H0 E1 F1 G1 H1 (E F G H - 0 1)
**   t6   A2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3 C3 D3 (A B C D - 2 3)
**   t7   E2 F2 G2 H2 E3 F3 G3 H3 (E F G H - 2 3) */
/* Phase 2: same with higher parts of the registers */
/*   A    A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
**   B    B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
**   C    C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
**   D    D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7
**   E    E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7
**   F    F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7
**   G    G0 G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7
**   H    H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 */
t0 = unpckhps (v[0], v[1]);
t0 = pshufhw (t0, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t0 = pshuflw (t0, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t1 = unpckhps (v[2], v[3]);
t1 = pshufhw (t1, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t1 = pshuflw (t1, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t2 = unpckhps (v[4], v[5]);
t2 = pshufhw (t2, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t2 = pshuflw (t2, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
t3 = unpckhps (v[6], v[7]);
t3 = pshufhw (t3, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 high */
t3 = pshuflw (t3, 0xD8); /* Flip middle 2 low */
/*   t0   A4 B4 A5 B5 A6 B6 A7 B7  (A B - 4 5 6 7)
**   t1   C4 D4 C5 D5 C6 D6 C7 D7  (C D - 4 5 6 7)
**   t2   E4 F4 E5 F5 E6 F6 E7 F7  (E F - 4 5 6 7)
**   t3   G4 H4 G5 H5 G6 H6 G7 H7  (G H - 4 5 6 7) */
/* Back to first part, v[0-3] can be re-written now */
/* L3 */
v[0] = unpcklpd (t4, t5);
v[1] = unpckhpd (t4, t5);
v[2] = unpcklpd (t6, t7);
v[3] = unpckhpd (t6, t7);
/* v[0] = A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 G0 H0
** v[1] = A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1
** v[2] = A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2
** v[3] = A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3 */
/* Back to second part, t[4-7] can be re-written now... */
/* L2 */
t4 = unpcklps (t0, t1);
t5 = unpcklps (t2, t3);
t6 = unpckhps (t0, t1);
t7 = unpckhps (t2, t3);
/*   t4   A4 B4 C4 D4 A5 B5 C5 D5 (A B C D - 4 5)
**   t5   E4 F4 G4 H4 E5 F5 G5 H5 (E F G H - 4 5)
**   t6   A6 B6 C6 D6 A7 B7 C7 D7 (A B C D - 6 7)
**   t7   E6 F6 G6 H6 E7 F7 G7 H7 (E F G H - 6 7) */
/* L3 */
v[4] = unpcklpd (t4, t5);
v[5] = unpckhpd (t4, t5);
v[6] = unpcklpd (t6, t7);
v[7] = unpckhpd (t6, t7);
/* v[4] = A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4
** v[5] = A5 B5 C5 D5 E5 F5 G5 H5
** v[6] = A6 B6 C6 D6 E6 F6 G6 H6
** v[7] = A7 B7 C7 D7 E7 F7 G7 H7 */
```

Each unpck* takes 3 cycles of latency, or 2 for reciprocal throughput (reported by Agner.) This is killing big part of the performance gains from using SSE (on this code) because this register dance takes almost one cycle per element. I tried to understand x264's asm file for x86 transpose but failed understanding the macros.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in 24 instructions total:

```
8 x _mm_unpacklo_epi16/_mm_unpackhi_epi16 (PUNPCKLWD/PUNPCKHWD)
8 x _mm_unpacklo_epi32/_mm_unpackhi_epi32 (PUNPCKLDQ/PUNPCKHDQ)
8 x _mm_unpacklo_epi64/_mm_unpackhi_epi64 (PUNPCKLQDQ/PUNPCKHQDQ)
```

Let me know if you need more details, but it's fairly obvious.

Comment: Nice one, mate! By any chance could you point me in some direction where to find more of the basic transformations with SSE?

Comment: @aleccolocco: there's not a lot of good material on SSE out there, unfortunately, at least for the more advanced topics. I recommend looking at AltiVec resources (e.g. on developer.apple.com) - a lot of AltiVec techniques translate easily to SSE.

Comment: Good news: I managed to do it. Bad news: only 5% performance gain measuring on 1M elements. But thanks, I've learned some cool SSE tricks!

Comment: @aleccolocco: if you're just doing a memory-to-memory transpose and nothing else then your performance may well be limited by memory bandwidth etc - in general you'll get much better overall performance if you can combine the transpose with other operations. Also note that SSE performance varies *hugely* between different CPU families: e.g. before Core 2 Duo = abysmal, Core 2 Duo = good, Core i7 = *rocks* !

Comment: @Paul R Yeah. I'm implementing "Efficient implementation of sorting on multi-core SIMD CPU architecture" and a few other things. My notebook's Merom seems to be 8x slower than their Xeon Penryn and don't want to even know how faster it would be on i7. Still, the 1M elements should be only 2MB and well inside the L2 here (so it's not bandwidth, I think.) Cheers!

Comment: @aleccolocco: OK, yes, it's probably your CPU that's the limiting factor then. Note also though that instruction scheduling may be an issue if you're using asm - you'll probably get better results using C instrinsics (_mm_unpackX_XXX) and let the C compiler do the scheduling. ICC is the best compiler for this, followed by gcc, followed by the execrable Visual Studio. Also if you can run on a 64 bit CPU then compile with -m64 so that you get 16 SSE registers rather than 8.

Comment: @PaulR: The performance difference is partly due to the "64-bit wall" in SSE: that the 128-bit SSE unit is formed from two separate 64-bit units, which causes a penalty whenever data needs to cross the 64-bit boundary. (Each 64-bit unit has its own registers) http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2008/v12i3/3-paper/3-super.htm
Also, try to use static single assignment form, to avoid issues with false data dependencies.

Comment: @rwong: that really only applies to old CPUs (prior to Core 2) - from Core 2 onwards Intel went for a full 128 bit SSE implementation

Comment: Since these functions accepts `__m128i`, does this approach not work with an 8x8 float matrix?

Comment: @DavidS: you would normally do a 4x4 transpose with floats, rather than 8x8, since you only get 4 floats per vector (i.e. you use 4 vectors). But the principle is the same, and you can still use SSE integer instructions to do the shuffling. And of course you can build larger transposes using the 4x4 vector transpose as a building block.

Comment: @PaulR, yeah thought so. Perhaps I can try using AVX-256, as I can fit eight 32-bits (floats) in each register.. any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: @DavidS: yes, you could do 8x8 with AVX, but it's a bit more fiddly due to the split lanes.

Comment: @PaulR: I've been fiddling with this for a while, but fail everytime. Would really like to get a working alternative using AVX2. Not to hijack more of this thread: is there a way I can perhaps contact you? If you want to keep your email private, you'll find mine at the bottom of the page: http://davidsteinsland.net/om-meg/

Comment: @DavidS: I'd be happy to help with this, but I think rather than take it off-line we should create a new question, so that any solutions will be available to others in the future. Feel free to ask the question, e.g. "How to do an 8x8 (float) transpose using AVX/AVX2 ?" and make sure you tag it as `simd`, `avx`, etc, and then I will get an automatic notification and can respond. You might also get some useful solutions from some of the other SIMD geeks on here at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do this myself, so here is my final result.  Note that the load and store instructions I have used are for 16-byte aligned arrays, which were declared using
**m128i* array = (__m128i*) _mm_malloc(N*sizeof(uint16_t), 16);
OR
int16_t array[N]__attribute**((aligned(16)));

```
__m128i *p_input  = (__m128i*)array;
__m128i *p_output = (__m128i*)array;
__m128i a = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i b = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i c = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i d = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i e = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i f = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i g = _mm_load_si128(p_input++);
__m128i h = _mm_load_si128(p_input);

__m128i a03b03 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(a, b);
__m128i c03d03 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(c, d);
__m128i e03f03 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(e, f);
__m128i g03h03 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(g, h);
__m128i a47b47 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(a, b);
__m128i c47d47 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(c, d);
__m128i e47f47 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(e, f);
__m128i g47h47 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(g, h);

__m128i a01b01c01d01 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(a03b03, c03d03);
__m128i a23b23c23d23 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(a03b03, c03d03);
__m128i e01f01g01h01 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(e03f03, g03h03);
__m128i e23f23g23h23 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(e03f03, g03h03);
__m128i a45b45c45d45 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(a47b47, c47d47);
__m128i a67b67c67d67 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(a47b47, c47d47);
__m128i e45f45g45h45 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(e47f47, g47h47);
__m128i e67f67g67h67 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(e47f47, g47h47);

__m128i a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a01b01c01d01, e01f01g01h01);
__m128i a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a01b01c01d01, e01f01g01h01);
__m128i a2b2c2d2e2f2g2h2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a23b23c23d23, e23f23g23h23);
__m128i a3b3c3d3e3f3g3h3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a23b23c23d23, e23f23g23h23);
__m128i a4b4c4d4e4f4g4h4 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a45b45c45d45, e45f45g45h45);
__m128i a5b5c5d5e5f5g5h5 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a45b45c45d45, e45f45g45h45);
__m128i a6b6c6d6e6f6g6h6 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a67b67c67d67, e67f67g67h67);
__m128i a7b7c7d7e7f7g7h7 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a67b67c67d67, e67f67g67h67);

_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h0);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a2b2c2d2e2f2g2h2);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a3b3c3d3e3f3g3h3);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a4b4c4d4e4f4g4h4);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a5b5c5d5e5f5g5h5);
_mm_store_si128(p_output++, a6b6c6d6e6f6g6h6);
_mm_store_si128(p_output, a7b7c7d7e7f7g7h7);
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea come from this http://www.randombit.net/bitbashing/programming/integer_matrix_transpose_in_sse2.html

I would segment the one 8x8 to four 4x4
and than do the mentioned trick.
finally swap the block(0,1) and block(1,0)

however, I still don't get what Paul R's trick.
Paul would you give me some more hits ?

Comment: The link is dead, but you can revive: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100111104515/http://www.randombit.net/bitbashing/programming/integer_matrix_transpose_in_sse2.html