# transpose 8x16 matrix on AVX 512

Tags: assembly, intrinsics, avx512

I have a 8x16 `uint32_t` matrix already loaded in 8 `zmm` registers. They have the layout

```
zmmi = {ai_15, ai_14, ..., ai_1, ai_0}
```

where `i` goes from 0 to 7 and `ai_j` are 32 bit integers for each `j` from 0 to 15. I am looking for a fast way of transforming the layout of these registers so that I obtain something that is not strictly a transpose of the matrix, but end result I want is to have a buffer in memory containing the 128 = 8 x 16 integers `ai_j` in the following layout

```
a0_0, a1_0, a2_0,..., a7_0, a0_1, a1_1, ..., a7_1,...,a0_15, a1_15, ...,a7_15
```

I am aware of the 16x16 transpositions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519222/how-to-transpose-a-16x16-matrix-using-simd-instructions) and in [Intel's implementation](https://github.com/intel/intel-ipsec-mb/blob/main/lib/include/transpose_avx512.asm#L204) but both rely on a trick of loading the matrix from memory in a precise layout to avoid 128 lane crossings. I cannot change the fact that I already have the matrix loaded in that particular way in 8 registers as described above. I can do this "transposition" on registers by 8 `vshufps` (throughput 1 and latency 1 on Xeon KNL) and 16 vpermi2d (throughput 1 latency 3) together with their index loading. A quick napking computation convinced me that this was the fastest way of doing this on registers before storing to memory and also that this was faster than trading some `vpermi2d` for scatter store operations to memory. The handwaving way of convincing myself of this is that I start with registers containing 1 letter and 16 indices (the macro below clarifies this notation) and I want to end up with a register containing 8 letters and 2 indices. At each `vshufps` and `vpermi2d` I can only divide by two the number of indices and multiply by 2 the number of letters. But I am forced to cross 128 bit lanes at least twice to separate contiguous indices; thus I am forced to have two rounds of non simple shuffles. I am hoping someone here could point me to a better way of doing this or confirm if this is alright. Here's my macro on GNU assembler, the 8 arguments `r0` --`r7` contain the 8 `zmm` registers above, the 4 `t0` -- `t3` are temporary clobbered `zmm` registers (it may be done with less, but I don't care about this) and `m0` and `m1` are preloaded masks:

```
.LPSHUFFLE_TRANSPOSE_MASK3:
    .long   0x00000000, 0x00000002, 0x00000010, 0x00000012
    .long   0x00000001, 0x00000003, 0x00000011, 0x00000013
    .long   0x00000004, 0x00000006, 0x00000014, 0x00000016
    .long   0x00000005, 0x00000007, 0x00000015, 0x00000017
                
.LPSHUFFLE_TRANSPOSE_MASK4:
    .long   0x00000008, 0x0000000a, 0x00000018, 0x0000001a
    .long   0x00000009, 0x0000000b, 0x00000019, 0x0000001b
    .long   0x0000000c, 0x0000000e, 0x0000001c, 0x0000001e
    .long   0x0000000d, 0x0000000f, 0x0000001d, 0x0000001f

# Input
#
# r0 = {a15 a14 a13 a12 a11 a10 a09 a08 a07 a06 a05 a04 a03 a02 a01 a00}
# r1 = {b15 g14 g13 g12 g11 g10 g09 g08 g07 g06 g05 g04 g03 g02 g01 g00}
# r2 = {c15 c14 c13 c12 c11 c10 c09 c08 c07 c06 c05 c04 c03 c02 c01 c00}
# r3 = {d15 d14 d13 d12 d11 d10 d09 d08 d07 d06 d05 d04 d03 d02 d01 d00}
# r4 = {e15 e14 e13 e12 e11 e10 e09 e08 e07 e06 e05 e04 e03 e02 e01 e00}
# r5 = {f15 f14 f13 f12 f11 f10 f09 f08 f07 f06 f05 f04 f03 f02 f01 f00}
# r6 = {g15 g14 g13 g12 g11 g10 g09 g08 g07 g06 g05 g04 g03 g02 g01 g00}
# r7 = {h15 h14 h13 h12 h11 h10 h09 h08 h07 h06 h05 h04 h03 h02 h01 h00}
# 
# OUTPUT:
# 
# r0 = {h01 g01 f01 e01 d01 c01 b01 a01 h00 g00 f00 e00 d00 c00 b00 a00}
# r1 = {h03 g03 f03 e03 d03 c03 b03 a03 h00 g02 f02 e02 d02 c02 b02 a02}
# r2 = {h05 g05 f05 e05 d05 c05 b05 a05 h00 g00 f00 e00 d00 c00 b00 a04}
# r3 = {h07 g07 f07 e07 d07 c07 b07 a07 h00 g00 f00 e00 d00 c00 b00 a06}
# r4 = {h09 g09 f09 e09 d09 c09 b09 a09 h00 g00 f00 e00 d00 c00 b00 a08}
# r5 = {h11 g11 f11 e11 d11 c11 b11 a11 h10 g10 f10 e10 d10 c10 b10 a10}
# r6 = {h13 g13 f13 e13 d13 c13 b13 a13 h12 g12 f12 e12 d12 c12 b12 a12}
# r7 = {h15 g15 f15 e15 d15 c15 b15 a15 h14 g14 f14 e14 d14 c14 b14 a14}
#
# m0 and m1 come already loaded with .LPSHUFFLE_TRANSPOSE_MASK3 and
# .LPSHUFFLE_TRANSPOSE_MASK4
.macro TRANSPOSE_8x16_U32 r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7,\
            t0, t1, t2, t3, m0, m1

    # Permutations: 2 letters, 8 indices
    vmovdqa32   \t0, \m0
    vmovdqa32   \t1, \m0
    vpermi2d    \t0, \r0, \r4   // t0 = {e7 e5 a7 a5 e6 e4 a6 a4 e3 e1 a3 a1 e2 e0 a2 a0}
    vpermi2d    \t1, \r1, \r5   // t1 = {f7 f5 b7 b5 f6 f4 b6 b4 f3 f1 b3 b1 f2 f0 b2 b0}
    vmovdqa32   \t2, \m1
    vmovdqa32   \t3, \m1
    vpermi2d    \t2, \r0, \r4   // t2 = {e15 e13 a15 a13 e14 e12 a14 a12 e11 e9 a11 a9 e10 e8 a10 a8}
    vpermi2d    \t3, \r1, \r5   // t3 = {f15 f13 b15 b13 f14 f12 b14 b12 f11 f9 b11 b9 f10 f8 a10 a8}

    vmovdqa32   \r0, \m0
    vmovdqa32   \r1, \m0
    vpermi2d    \r0, \r2, \r6   // r0 = {g7 g5 c7 c5 g6 g4 c6 c4 g3 g1 c3 c1 g2 g0 c2 c0}
    vpermi2d    \r1, \r3, \r7   // r1 = {h7 h5 d7 d5 h6 h4 d6 d4 h3 h1 d3 d1 h2 h0 d2 d0}

    vmovdqa32   \r4, \m1
    vmovdqa32   \r5, \m1
    vpermi2d    \r4, \r2, \r6   // r4 = {g15 g13 c15 c13 g14 g12 c14 c12 g11 g9 c11 c9 g10 g8 c10 c8}
    vpermi2d    \r5, \r3, \r7   // r5 = {h15 h13 d15 d13 h14 h12 d14 d12 h11 h9 d11 d9 h10 h8 d10 d8}

    # Simple shuffles: 4 letters, 4 indices
    vshufps     \r6, \t0, \t1, 0x88 // r6 = {f5 b5 e5 a5 f4 b4 e4 a4 f1 b1 e1 a1 f0 b0 e0 a0}
    vshufps     \r7, \t0, \t1, 0xDD // r7 = {f7 b7 e7 a7 f6 b6 e6 a6 f3 b3 e3 a3 f2 b2 e2 a2}
    vshufps     \t1, \t2, \t3, 0x88 // t1 = {f13 b13 e13 a13 f12 b12 e12 a12 f9 b9 e9 a9 f8 b8 e8 a8}
    vshufps     \t0, \t2, \t3, 0xDD // t0 = {f15 b15 e15 a15 f14 b14 e14 a14 f11 b11 e11 a11 f10 b10 e10 a10}
    vshufps     \t2, \r4, \r5, 0x88 // t2 = {h13 d13 g13 c13 h12 d12 g12 c12 h9 d9 g9 c9 h8 d8 g8 c8}
    vshufps     \t3, \r4, \r5, 0xDD // t3 = {h15 d15 g15 c15 h14 d14 g14 c14 h11 d11 g11 c11 h10 d10 g10 c10}
    vshufps     \r4, \r0, \r1, 0x88 // r4 = {h5 d5 g5 c5 h4 d4 g4 c4 h1 d1 g1 c1 h0 d0 g0 c0}
    vshufps     \r5, \r0, \r1, 0xDD // r5 = {h7 d7 g7 c7 h6 d6 g6 c6 h3 d3 g3 c3 h2 d2 g2 c2}

    # Final permutations: 2 letters, 8 indices
    vmovdqa32   \r0, \m0
    vmovdqa32   \r1, \m0 
    vpermi2d    \r0, \r6, \r4   // r0 = {h1 g1 f1 e1 d1 c1 b1 a1 h0 g0 f0 e0 d0 c0 b0 a0}
    vpermi2d    \r1, \r7, \r5   // r1 = {h3 g3 f3 e3 d3 c3 b3 a3 h2 g2 f2 e2 d2 c2 b2 a2}
    vmovdqa32   \r2, \m1
    vmovdqa32   \r3, \m1 
    vpermi2d    \r2, \r6, \r4   // r2 = {h5 g5 f5 e5 d5 c5 b5 a5 h4 g4 f4 e4 d4 c4 b4 a4}
    vpermi2d    \r3, \r7, \r5   // r3 = {h7 g7 f7 e7 d7 c7 b7 a7 h6 g6 f6 e6 d6 c6 b6 a6}


    vmovdqa32   \r4, \m0
    vmovdqa32   \r5, \m0 
    vpermi2d    \r4, \t1, \t2   // r4 = {h9 g9 f9 e9 d9 c9 b9 a9 h8 g8 f8 e8 d8 c8 b8 a8}
    vpermi2d    \r5, \t0, \t3   // r5 = {h11 g11 f11 e11 d11 c11 b11 a11 h10 g10 f10 e10 d10 c10 b10 a10}
    vmovdqa32   \r6, \m1
    vmovdqa32   \r7, \m1 
    vpermi2d    \r6, \t1, \t2   // r6 = {h13 g13 f13 e13 d13 c13 b13 a13 h12 g12 f12 e12 d12 c12 b12 a12}
    vpermi2d    \r7, \t0, \t3   // r7 = {h15 g15 f15 e15 d15 c15 b15 a15 h14 g14 f14 e14 d14 c14 b14 a14}
.endm
```

Comment: Right, you definitely don't want scatter stores.  If the data starts in memory, it's worth considering loading in 256-bit halves with `vmovups ymm` / `vinsertf32x8 zmm, [mem], 1`.  CPUs other than KNL have 2/clock load throughput.  (Ice Lake and later have 2/clock stores, but can only commit to cache at 2/clock when a pair of consecutive stores both write the same cache line.  2/clock loads are more flexible and are a thing even on Skylake-avx512 CPUs.)