# How to transpose a 8x8 int64 matrix with AVX512

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose, simd, avx512

Consider 8 AVX512 registers containing rows of a matrix, so that each 64-bit lane is a cell of an 8x8 matrix. How to transpose such a matrix in C/C++?

What I have tried so far: 8 `_mm512_i32scatter_epi64()` intrinsics. It's extremely slow and uses the cache heavily so that other CPU cores can't get enough L3 bandwidth.

Comment: @harold do you mean `_mm512_permutex2var_epi64()` intrinsic or something else?

Comment: A bunch of those yes. This should be possible with 3 rounds of "quadrant swapping", ie exchanging the 4x4 off-diagonal quadrants of the 8x8 matrix, then exchanging 2x2 quadrants within each 4x4 block and then exchanging the off-diagonal entries of each 2x2 block

Comment: That would be 24 shuffles in total I think, which isn't great.. maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519222/how-to-transpose-a-16x16-matrix-using-simd-instructions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622745/transpose-an-8x8-float-using-avx-avx2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: *uses the cache heavily so that other CPU cores can't get enough L3 bandwidth.* - What?  An 8x8 i64 matrix fits in 512 bytes; that's 8 cache lines.  It shouldn't matter much how you access them, whether it's one store miss or 8, a single core will only have one off-core RFO (read for ownership) per cache line outstanding to L3.  Unless you're talking about the other *logical* core on the same physical core being starved of load/store uop and cache throughput?  (But scatters are slower than gathers, and stores have worse throughput than loads in general, so I still wouldn't use scatter.)

Answer (score 1):

If the values are originally in RAM, try `_mm512_i32gather_epi64` instead. Simultaneous reading from cache could lead to less stalling than writing to it.

If the destination is memory, dummy writing zeroes to a cache-line-aligned destination area could ensure that the instructions don't stall waiting on cache. With the scatter instructions the CPU doesn't know that whole destination area will be overwritten, so it has to wait for loading of the previous values.

If the values are already in registers and the goal is to keep them in registers, [_mm512_permutex2var_pd](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm512_permutex2var_pd&expand=4274) seems like the most useful instruction. It lets to pick individual elements by index from two sources. But because values are distributed across so many registers, shuffling them into place will take a lot of operations.

I'll mark the matrix rows A-H and columns 0-7. Initially each register will contain one row, which I'll mark e.g. `A0-7`. Goal is to have each register contain one column, marked e.g. `A-H0`.

```
A0 .. A7
..    ..
H0 .. H7
```

The best sequence I found is still 24 shuffles:

1. Do 8 shuffles on pairs of registers in blocks of 4:

   - Combine `A0-7` and `B0-7` to `A-B0-3`
   - Combine `A0-7` and `B0-7` to `A-B4-7`
   - ...
   - Combine `G0-7` and `H0-7` to `G-H4-7`
2. Do 8 shuffles in blocks of 2:

   - Combine `A-B0-3` and `C-D0-3` to `A-D0-1`
   - Combine `A-B0-3` and `C-D0-3` to `A-D2-3`
   - ...
   - Combine `E-F4-7` and `G-H4-7` to `E-H6-7`
3. Do 8 shuffles in blocks of 1:

   - Combine `A-D0-1` and `E-H0-1` to `A-H0`
   - Combine `A-D0-1` and `E-H0-1` to `A-H1`
   - ...
   - Combine `A-D6-7` and `E-H6-7` to `A-H7`

I think this is the minimum possible number of shuffles when operating only in registers. Each AVX512 instruction takes at most two registers as input, and this sequence takes full advantage of the inputs and outputs to gather data from the 8 source registers.

Comment: Indeed, gather instructions are *much* faster than scatter (especially on Intel; Zen 4 has fairly slow gathers as well as even worse scatters).  https://uops.info/ - Ice Lake has 1 per 5 cycle throughput for `vpgatherdq zmm` (8x 32-bit indexes, 8x 64-bit data).  Alder Lake / Sapphire Rapids improves that to 3 cycles.  But `vpgatherdq zmm` is many more uops, and 7 cycle throughput.  (Order matters for stores, not for loads.)

Comment: But these are likely still worse than plain loads (perhaps in 256-bit halves with `vinsert...` to get the shuffling started) and register shuffles, since AVX-512 has *very* good shuffles like `vpermt2q` as you mention, grabbing arbitrary elements from 2 source vectors  (`_mm512_permutex2var_epi64` for integer.  Intel's guide only lists `_mm512_mask_permutex2var_epi64`).   1/clock throughput for it on Intel and Zen 4, for `__m512i` width.

Comment: Zen 4 has 2/clock throughput for `vpermt2q` with 256-bit vectors, and using smaller vectors might mean less total shuffling if you're storing back to memory.  Less total shuffling if you're counting how many 256-bit shuffle operations it cost, where one 512-bit shuffle counts as 2.  So 16x 256-bit shuffles each in blocks of 2 then 1, skipping the blocks of 4 step.

Comment: Probably at least one block-size of shuffle doesn't need a full `vpermt2q`, instead maybe being doable with an in-lane `vshufpd` (`_mm512_cast...` to `__m512d` and back to `__m512i` in C++), or with `vshuff64x2` with immediates to interleave 128-bit lanes.  Those are is still port-5 only on Intel, though.  `vshufpd ymm` can run 2/clock on Intel Ice Lake and later, but with any ZMM uops in flight, the vector ALUs on port 1 are shut down, including the extra shuffle unit on port 1 that can handle some but not all shuffles.  So we might save on vector constants and reg-copy instructions.